# React Native Passing Props through Nested Navigators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Hi I was wonder how I could pass props down the navigators or if there's a better way of designing my structure.

```
const MangaTabRouter = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
{
    Info: { screen: Manga },
    Chapter: { screen: Chapter }
  }
);

const Stack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: { 
      screen: MangaTabRouter,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: props => <CustomHeader {...props} />
      }
    }
  }
);

const HomeScreenRouter = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    MyLibrary: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Sources: { screen: Sources },
    Manga: { screen: Stack }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />,
    initialRouteName: "MyLibrary"
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(HomeScreenRouter);
```

I then have a button that calls the Main URI and goes there as well as passing in some props.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Main', {data});
```

Currently, I use dangerouslyGetParent() to access the props but I find it not appropriate for my design and also it doesn't work with multiple Manga entries (ie. props don't change). I would ideally like to pass props (the data object) to both the Info and Chapter URIs under the tab navigator. I assume it has to do with passing props to the router itself? So my question is: is it possible to send props to sub children as well or would I have to somehow redesign my routers to pass in a component to Main that then has MangaTabRouter as a child component within it? Also, is there a way to pass the props that I sent to Info to the header as well? I'm experimenting but coming up empty handed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const MangaTabRouter = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Info: { screen: props => <Manga {...props}/> },
    Chapter: { screen: props => <Chapter {...props}/> }
  }
);

class ExtendStack extends React.Component {
  static router = MangaTabRouter.router;
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return <MangaTabRouter navigation={navigation} screenProps={navigation.state.params} />;
  }
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: { 
      screen: ExtendStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: props => <CustomHeader {...props} />
      }
    }
  }
);
```

I had to use screenProps to pass in the new information. I'll take a closer look at the header and try with a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the data as item: `this.props.navigation.navigate('Main', {data : item})`

and call `this.props.navigation.state.params.data` in your child component

Comment: Sorry, what I had meant was that I wanted to propagate my props from Main to Info and Chapter. I was wondering if there is a way to do that.